# First Order Differential Equantion (Ordinary) question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm in second year of college (Programming and Games Development) and I have a calculus exam tomorrow. I have a maths problem I can't solve.

> **(c)** Solve the following differential equation using an Integrating Factor:
> $$x\frac{dy}{dx}-y=x^2$$

I can't solve it and I've looked at MANY videos online but none of them were any help.

Comment: Could you explain that a bit more in depth please?

Answer (score 3):

Denote $y'={dy\over dx}$ and divide the equation by $x^2$ (integrating factor $1/x^2$), keeping in mind $x'=1$  to get

$${xy'-yx'\over x^2}=\left({y\over x}\right)'=1$$

And so with $C$ a constant

$${y\over x}=x+C$$